# Not getting JSON response with GET Request

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm creating Rest Services for Android application and trying to fetch some data from DB, but i'm getting empty JSON, actually i'm getting nothing, but also i'm getting no error there.

Here is the structure of my DB:

[image: DB]

This is my function where i'm executing query:

```
public function getAllJokes() {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, joke, user_name, image, created_at FROM jokes ORDER BY created_at DESC");
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $jokes = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    return $jokes;
}
```

And here is the GET request:

```
$app->get('/all_jokes', function() use ($app) {

$response = array();
$db = new DbHandler();

// fetching all jokes
$result = $db->getAllJokes();

$response["error"] = false;
$response["jokes"] = array();

// looping throught result and preparing jokes array
while ($joke = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp["id"] = $joke["id"];
    $tmp["joke"] = $joke["joke"];
    $tmp["user_name"] = $joke["user_name"];
    array_push($response["jokes"], $tmp);
}

echoResponse(200, $response);
});
```

So when i try to fetch data, i'm getting nothing. I have 5 records in TABLE.

Comment: is this url something you can share for us to test?

Comment: What do you mean by empty JSON?

Comment: That tiny screenshot is both illegible and irrelevant. Try and keep your question as uncluttered as possible, it helps people understand what you're asking and get you an answer.

Comment: @Juan Cortes No, i'm testing this on localhost

Comment: I mean, i'm not getting any Json response.

Comment: Where is the definition of `echoResponse`?

Comment: @tadman Click on images to see them expanded.

Comment: echoResponse function is working fine in other requests.

Comment: @Barmar Sometimes that works, sometimes it doesn't. It's still a pointless image. `SHOW CREATE TABLE` pasted as plain text is always better, and makes it easy to test on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). It doesn't accept images as schema.

Comment: I will do it now. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12c95

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code for the complete solution.

```
<?php
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","db_employee") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select * from tbl_employee";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Not getting anything.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic i have updated my answer kindly check.

Comment: Empty page. The code is okay, but i'm getting no result.

Comment: Yes. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Have a look in the access log and error log of your webserver.

Comment: If you are getting empty page that's mean you're getting error some where Inside your **php.ini** check `display_errors = on` and restart your webserver